# custom listview in reverse order

Tags: java, android, listview

I am taking data from a activity, saving it to sqlite db and showing it in listview. But I want it to show the list in reverse order . This is my list view viewing activity.
I am not able to understand what should I add for reverse order listview

Edit: where should I add Collection.reverse(arraylist);

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_sqlite_data);

        LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ID_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

        NAME_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

        PHONE_NUMBER_Array = new ArrayList<String>();

        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);

        LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowSingleRecordActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("ListViewClickedItemValue", ListViewClickItemArray.get(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        ShowSQLiteDBdata() ;

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {

        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME+"", null);

        ID_Array.clear();
        NAME_Array.clear();
        PHONE_NUMBER_Array.clear();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                ID_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_ID)));

                //Inserting Column ID into Array to Use at ListView Click Listener Method.
                ListViewClickItemArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_ID)));

                NAME_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_1_Name)));

                PHONE_NUMBER_Array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Table_Column_2_PhoneNumber)));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(DisplaySQLiteDataActivity.this,

                ID_Array,
                NAME_Array,
                PHONE_NUMBER_Array
        );

        LISTVIEW.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `Collections.reverse(arrayList);` for the `arrayList `you want to reverse then reset the adapter with the reversed `arrayList`, it will work very smoothly.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar should I change something in the code I have shown above ,where should I add    Collection.reverse(arraylist);

Comment: Just put it wherever you want to reverse the list like on a onClick or in a method. Reverse the arraylists, Re-initialize the listAdapter like you did above with those three arrayList and then set the adapter to the list.

Comment: Edit - as you want to reverse the list initially, put `Collections.reverse(yourArraList);` for all your three lists - idArray, nameArray and phoneNoArray just before initializing the listAdapter. That's all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Modify your code as below:

```
Collections.reverse(ID_Array);
Collections.reverse(NAME_Array);
Collections.reverse(PHONE_NUMBER_Array);
listAdapter = new ListAdapter(DisplaySQLiteDataActivity.this,    
                ID_Array,
                NAME_Array,
                PHONE_NUMBER_Array
        );    
LISTVIEW.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This is what you need, this way your lists will be reversed even before initializing the adapter and your adapter will then have the reversed values which basically means a reversed adapter.

Comment: Thank-you so much bro for ur answer

Comment: But when I click any item it open wrong id item because if reverse order how do I set my idholder to total-selecteditem

Comment: @ShubhamJangle What are you using for holding the IDs? if that's an array or a list, you can reverse that too.

Comment: I'm using IDholder = getIntent().getStringExtra("ListViewClickedItemValue");

Comment: @ShubhamJangle try using `intent.putExtra("ListViewClickedItemValue", listAdapter.getItem(position));`.